# Google Cloud Spanner not implementing check constraint

Tags: google-cloud-spanner

When trying to create a table with `gcloud` CLI (using the *spanner emulator*)

```
gcloud spanner databases ddl update db_name --instance=instance_name --ddl=$data
```

I'm attempting to add a check constraint where `$data` evaluates to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    my_key STRING(36),
    some_column STRING(100),
    CONSTRAINT ck_my_table_some_column_enum CHECK (some_column = 'this' OR some_column = 'that'),
) PRIMARY KEY (my_key)
```

and keep getting the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.spanner.databases.ddl.update) HttpError accessing <http://localhost:9020/v1/projects/spanner-emulator-test/instances/instance_name/databases/db_name/ddl?alt=json>: response: <{'content-type': 'application/json', 'trailer': 'Grpc-Trailer-Content-Type', 'date': 'Tue, 31 Aug 2021 22:53:52 GMT', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'status': 501}>, content <{"error":"Check Constraint is not implemented.","code":12,"message":"Check Constraint is not implemented."}>
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

First inclination might be to verify the emulator is running given the last part of the message.  It is.  And I've tried immediately executing the same DDL *without* the check constraint and it works perfectly - table is created.

#### DBeaver

I've also tried creating this table using the `DBeaver` db tool and get the following error:

```java
org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [12]: UNIMPLEMENTED: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Check Constraint is not implemented.
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:133)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:513)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:444)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:171)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:431)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:816)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3440)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:118)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:171)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:116)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4718)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcSqlExceptionFactory$JdbcSqlExceptionImpl: UNIMPLEMENTED: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Check Constraint is not implemented.
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcSqlExceptionFactory.of(JdbcSqlExceptionFactory.java:222)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.AbstractJdbcStatement.execute(AbstractJdbcStatement.java:259)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeStatement(JdbcStatement.java:110)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:106)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)
    at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerException: UNIMPLEMENTED: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Check Constraint is not implemented.
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerExceptionPreformatted(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:284)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:61)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.fromApiException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:299)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:174)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.SpannerExceptionFactory.newSpannerException(SpannerExceptionFactory.java:110)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseAdminClientImpl.lambda$updateDatabaseDdl$7(DatabaseAdminClientImpl.java:337)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$ApiFunctionToGuavaFunction.apply(ApiFutures.java:240)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture$CatchingFuture.doFallback(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:223)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture$CatchingFuture.doFallback(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:211)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture.run(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:124)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:30)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1213)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:724)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.addListener(FluentFuture.java:110)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:52)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractCatchingFuture.create(AbstractCatchingFuture.java:41)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.catching(Futures.java:297)
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.catching(ApiFutures.java:99)
    at com.google.api.gax.longrunning.OperationFutureImpl.<init>(OperationFutureImpl.java:97)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.DatabaseAdminClientImpl.updateDatabaseDdl(DatabaseAdminClientImpl.java:335)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.DdlClient.executeDdl(DdlClient.java:89)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.DdlClient.executeDdl(DdlClient.java:84)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.SingleUseTransaction.lambda$executeDdlAsync$1(SingleUseTransaction.java:272)
    at io.grpc.Context$2.call(Context.java:596)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:69)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractBaseUnitOfWork$SpannerAsyncExecutionException: Execution failed for statement: CREATE TABLE my_table (
    my_key STRING(36),
    some_column STRING(100),
    CONSTRAINT ck_my_table_some_column_enum CHECK (some_column = 'this' OR some_column = 'that'),
) PRIMARY KEY (my_key)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractBaseUnitOfWork.executeStatementAsync(AbstractBaseUnitOfWork.java:233)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.AbstractBaseUnitOfWork.executeStatementAsync(AbstractBaseUnitOfWork.java:145)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.SingleUseTransaction.executeDdlAsync(SingleUseTransaction.java:281)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionImpl.executeDdlAsync(ConnectionImpl.java:1157)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.connection.ConnectionImpl.execute(ConnectionImpl.java:803)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.AbstractJdbcStatement.execute(AbstractJdbcStatement.java:250)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeStatement(JdbcStatement.java:110)
        at com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:106)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.execute(JDBCStatementImpl.java:330)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.impl.jdbc.exec.JDBCStatementImpl.executeStatement(JDBCStatementImpl.java:130)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeStatement(SQLQueryJob.java:513)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.lambda$0(SQLQueryJob.java:444)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:171)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.executeSingleQuery(SQLQueryJob.java:431)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.execute.SQLQueryJob.extractData(SQLQueryJob.java:816)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.editors.sql.SQLEditor$QueryResultsContainer.readData(SQLEditor.java:3440)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.lambda$0(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:118)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.exec.DBExecUtils.tryExecuteRecover(DBExecUtils.java:171)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetJobDataRead.run(ResultSetJobDataRead.java:116)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.ui.controls.resultset.ResultSetViewer$ResultSetDataPumpJob.run(ResultSetViewer.java:4718)
        at org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.runtime.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Check Constraint is not implemented.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:535)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:533)
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
    at com.google.cloud.spanner.spi.v1.SpannerErrorInterceptor$1$1.onClose(SpannerErrorInterceptor.java:100)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:557)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:69)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:738)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:717)
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check constraints is available in the latest version of emulator. Can you please check and get back to us if there are issues.

https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/cloud-spanner-emulator/global/emulator@sha256:ef0fd2ec74bb17b6c31e5010fb699fd0009b9829721d5159e6a11b6a40f881f1/details

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you. I didn't see that update for `1.3.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Well... it looks like check constraints don't seem to work with the emulator.  I tried this with a test db in the console and it worked.  If anyone comes up with a solution to this, however, or if there's something I need to configure, please let me know!  Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing that you can configure or do to solve this at the moment. The emulator currently does not support CHECK CONSTRAINTS. There's a list of supported/unsupported features here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-spanner-emulator#features-and-limitations, but it unfortunately does not mention it as being unsupported.

Comment: UPDATE: The Spanner emulator supports CHECK CONSTRAINTS from version 1.3.0.